# I need a little help with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

I need a little help with `.htaccess` file I have songs, singers and albums links I want to rewrite.

I all ready rewrote the links and they are like this:
the links for the songs is like this:

`/song/song_name`

for singers:

`/singer_name`

for albums:

`/album_name`

From my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^singer/([^/\.]+)/?$ /core/controller.php?singer=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^song/([^/\.]+)/?$ /core/controller.php?song=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^album/([^/\.]+)/?$ /core/controller.php?album=$1 [L]
```

I need the links for the songs, singers and albums to be like this:

for songs `/singer_name/song_name`

for singers `/singer_name`

for albums `/singer_name/album_name`

can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in .htaccess unless you pre-define (hard code) all names in advance (well, you can use RewruteMap but that is close to hard-coding). The reason is -- how can you identify what is song_name and what is album_name if they both have the same syntax? Also .. sometimes you have situations when album name is a song name at the same time (album named after the song) -- how can you identify which one is which?

**You have few options here:**

1) **Redirect everything to your `controller.php`** and implement routing logic inside (using PHP only). There you can query database and see what the actual parameter is -- album or song.

2) **Implement 3-tier URL structure** (this will allow RewriteRules to properly identify what is what):

`/singer-name` for singers

`/singer-name/album-name` for albums

`/singer-name/album-name/song-name` for songs

3) **Add some additional info/code into URL** so mod_rewrite can see the difference between album-name & song_name. For example:

`/singer-name` for singers

`/singer-name/album-name_a` for albums (`_a` will tell that this is the album)

`/singer-name/song-name_s` for songs (`_s` will tell that this is the song)

or

`/singer-name/s_song-name` for songs

or add no such code for songs, as albums URLs will have such code already.

---

I personally prefer #2 -- it has more logical hierarchy.

---

**UPDATE:** These are the rules for scenario #2. You can use these characters: any latin letter (upper and lower case), digits, underscore `_` and minus `-`. This will cover the following URLs:

`/britney-spears` -- singer url

`/britney-spears/Femme-Fatale` -- album url

`/britney-spears/Femme-Fatale/Till-the-World-Ends` -- song url

```
RewriteEngine On
# Do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
# work with artist URLs
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)$ /core/controller.php?singer=$1 [NS,QSA,L]
# work with album URLs
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)$ /core/controller.php?singer=$1&album=$2 [NS,QSA,L]
# work with songs URLs
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)$ /core/controller.php?singer=$1&album=$2&song=$3 [NS,QSA,L]
```

It's up to you if you going to use all lower case letters or mixed-case. I would recommend all lower case for consistency.

Comment: yeah i prefer the #2 as well but how can i actually do it because i'm new to regular expressions... btw.. i'm identifying them through a singer_url or song_url or album_url columns in the database.

Comment: Database column names are irrelevant here. If you are talking about the actual URLs (`album_name` vs `album-name`) then the second one is recommended (use `-` instead of `_` ). I will update my answer with exact rules for #2 scenario.