# help with htaccess code for navigation

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need a little help with .htaccess rewrite](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15560/i-need-a-little-help-with-htaccess-rewrite)

Hello,
I need a little help with `.htaccess` file. I have songs, singers and albums links I want to rewrite.

I already rewrote the links and they are like this:

- for the songs is like this: `/song/song_name`
- for singers: `/singer_name`
- for albums: `/album_name`

This is the code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^singer/([^/\.]+)/?$ /core/controller.php?singer=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^song/([^/\.]+)/?$ /core/controller.php?song=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^album/([^/\.]+)/?$ /core/controller.php?album=$1 [L]
```

I need the links for the songs, singers and albums to be like this:

- for songs `/singer_name/song_name`
- for singers `/singer_name`
- for albums `/singer_name/album_name`

Can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for **/singer_name** add:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(singer|song|album)
RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)/?$ /core/controller.php?singer=$1 [L]
```

for **/singer_name/song_name** add:

> ```
> RewriteCond $1 !^(singer|song|album)
> RewriteCond $3 !^(album)
> RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)(/([^/\.]+))?.*$ /core/controller.php?singer=$1&song=$3 [L]
> ```

for **/singer_name/album/album_name** add:

> ```
> RewriteCond $1 !^(singer|song|album)
> RewriteCond $3 (album)
> RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)(/([^/\.]+))?.*$ /core/controller.php?singer=$1&album=$3 [L]
> ```

**edit:**

Sorry, but rewriting: **/singer_name/song_name** and **/singer_name/album_name** can not be done at the same time, as Apache doesn't know the difference between Song name and Album name, unless all song name start with numbers like: **01. Song Name**
 etc.

Comment: yeah i figured this out at the first time i tried this, i went back to previuos solution for songs `/song/song_name` singer: `/singer/singer_name` albums `/album/album_name`.